# Use jquery plugin in coffeescript

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I have this code with javascript, it's a call to a [flip jQuery Plugin](http://guilhemmarty.com/flippy) . How do i convert this call to a plugin to coffeescript?

```
$("#"+d).flippy({
    duration: "500",
    verso: '<img src="/img/texture_suelo.jpg" class="img50x50>">'
});
```

*Note: The argument seems to be json.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CoffeeScript syntax for your above code is the following:

```
$("#" + d).flippy
  duration: "500"
  verso: "<img src=\"/img/texture_suelo.jpg\" class=\"img50x50>\">"
```

I'm not sure I completely understand the question...however, there is a nice little web based utility for converting JS to CS and vice versa:

http://js2coffee.org/